# Different domains on different ip addresses in apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hosting, virtualhost

I am trying to setup apache for serving different domains from different ip addresses.

Here is what I did in domain.conf in sites-available :

```
<VirtualHost 199.111.222.333>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
      ServerAdmin **********@gmail.com
      ServerName domain1.com
      ServerAlias www.domain1.com

      # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
      DirectoryIndex  index.php
      DocumentRoot /home/ApacheWebsites/domain1

      # Custom log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog /home/ApacheWebsites/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /home/ApacheWebsites/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory /home/ApacheWebsites/domain1/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and for the second, I create another domain2.conf and put same content as above , only changing IP address. But its working fine for the domain1.com, but domain2.com is not working at all, and neither the ip address I want for the second domain is showing apache default page.

Comment: Having all the domain1.conf, domain2.conf,..etc in `sites-available` directory isn't enough; have you `enabled` the sites by running this command`sudo a2ensite domain2`, `sudo a2ensite domain3` etc. ?

Comment: I solved it. I had to add entry for ip addresses in /network/interface